# Python: How to best create a dictionary from another dictionary in a library

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparative-review

I have the following code which builds up a dictionary of endpoints that I iterate through later on. Is this the cleanest, most scalable and performant way?

I was thinking of adding a list as a key to the library file with keywords but I didn't think that was maintainable.

The code works in both scenarios, and as mentioned, just wondering what the most cleanest, scalable and performant way was. if not either of the two below, then what else?

**Main Version 1**

```
import graphnet_endpoints   # CUSTOM

dict_endpoints = graphnet_endpoints.main()
endpoints = {}
endpoints['Allergies'] = dict_endpoints['allergies']
endpoints['Contraindictions'] = dict_endpoints['contraindictions']
endpoints['Medication Repeat'] = dict_endpoints['meds_repeat']
endpoints['Medication Issued'] = dict_endpoints['meds_issued']
```

**Library Version 1**

```
endpoints = {
    'allergies': {
        'pretty': 'Allergies',
        'api_url':'{}/allergies/patients/{}/allergies-summary',
        'stored_procedure': 'spAllergies',
        'keys': ['eds']
    },
    'contraindictions': {
        'pretty': 'Contraindictions',
        'api_url':'{}/gp/patients/{}/gp-contraindications',
        'stored_procedure': 'spContraindications',
        'keys': ['eds']
    },
    'meds_repeat': {
        'pretty': 'Medications - Repeat',
        'api_url':'{}/gp/patients/{}/gp-medications/repeat',
        'stored_procedure': 'spMedicationRepeat',
        'keys': ['eds']
    },
    'meds_issued': {
        'pretty': 'Medications - Issued',
        'api_url':'{}/gp/patients/{}/gp-medications/issued',
        'stored_procedure': 'spMedicationIssued',
        'keys': ['eds']
    }
}

def main():
    return endpoints
```

Alternative I had in mind was:

**Main Version 2**

```
import graphnet_endpoints   # CUSTOM
endpoints = {}
for x in graphnet_endpoints.main('eds'):
    endpoints[x['pretty']] = x
```

**Library Version 2**

```
# THE DICTIONARY FROM EXAMPLE ABOVE GOES HERE
def main(key = 'nowt'):
    """
    Returning the endpoints
    """
    for k,v in endpoints.items():
        if key in v['keys']:
            yield v
```

Comment: The current question title applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [ask] for examples, and revise the title accordingly.

Comment: Ha - sorry - I must have cut it off accidentally

Comment: Does your current code work or is it an approach you have in mind that's not yet tested? If you look at the [help/on-topic], you'll notice we're quite good at reviewing code that's actually doing something but don't deal with hypothetical situations. We can't see what's in your library, but you seem to be building a dictionary by hand. That can't possibly be the most maintainable way indeed.

Comment: Have amended. it works. I added two scenarios. I was wondering which one was better in terms of scalability, performance and maintenance. It seems to me the 2nd version would be better in terms of scalability and maintenance but not performance.